# Standard Deviation and Standard Mean Error of measurement with uncertainties

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, measurement-error, error-propagation

It is well known that, given a set of $n$ values $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$, its Sample Standard Deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})}$ and its Standard Mean Error is $\sigma_{\bar{x}}=\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. But how do we calculate the standard deviation and standard mean error if these same measurements have an uncertainty (i.e., $3.59 \pm 0.01$, $3.63 \pm 0.01$, etc.), so that $X_i = Y_i \pm U_i$?

I came up with four possible methods of resolution:

1. Estimating the error from how accurately we think we can do the measurement. This would mean calculating the Sample Standard Error assuming the uncertainties in the individual measurements as the standard deviation (i.e., in the case shown in parentheses above, $0.01$). Thus, we would have $E = \sigma_{\bar{x}} = \dfrac{U_i}{\sqrt{n}}$.
2. Calculating the Standard Deviation $\sigma$ of the $n$ values and using that as an estimate of the error: we would have the usual $\mathrm{Mean} \pm \mathrm{Standard \ Deviation}$.
3. Calculating the Standard Deviation $\sigma$ of the $n$ values to evaluate the Standard Mean Error. We would have the usual $E = \sigma_{\bar{x}} = \dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n \ (n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})}$.
4. Taking into account the standard deviations of the errors in the observations, I could calculate the error as $$E = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (\operatorname{Var}(Y_i) + \operatorname{Var}(U_i))} = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i^2} \qquad \textrm{with} \qquad\sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})} = \mathrm{Standard \ Deviation}.$$
   The problem is that hardly ever in such estimates is $\sigma$ calculated, because it is usually estimated from experimental observation. So how to solve this problem?

Could you explain which of the four methods is the most convincing, giving reasons for each? That is, which is the right way to go and the correct method to apply?

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Comment: ANOVA is the standard technique.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, Sir. But ANOVA contains many aspects, doesn't it? What specific aspects of Analysis of Variance should I connect to what I wrote in my question?

Comment: "ANOVA" means "analysis of variance."  This is intended in the sense of using *variance* to *separate* ["analyze"] a random response into disjoint factors and to identify or characterize those factors (such as "within group" and "between group" variances).  That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @whuber Thanks again. Would you have specific references to guide me on how to solve my problem?